# Adjustable Angle for a 1.5 inch OLED screen

Tags: 3d-design

I have a 1.5 inch screen, and I would like to create an adjustable angle plate for the screen, similar to Game boy advanced (shown below)

Does anyone know how the mechanism works?
By any chance, is there an adjustable connector that I can put on a 3D printed part to make an adjustable angle plate?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to design a hinge in two parts, probably with a third and fourth part as a cover.

The unit holds position by friction, so it will get sloppier with use as the plastic wears, or you may want to use a metal shaft and bushings.  This will also be affected by the mass of the screen and the torque onto the hinge.

From your image, you can clearly see which hoops in the hinge are part of the top and which are coming up from the bottom.

The ribbon cable will pass between the lower and upper in the middle where the two wide hoops are, and not through the ends which will provide the bulk of the support.

---

If you want to make a case exactly like this, then consider buying a shell instead.   The ifixit step-by-step instructions at https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nintendo+Game+Boy+Advance+SP++Shell+Replacement/137582 are clear and helpful for a complete organ-transplant.

The hinge/clutch mechanism used in these is a marvel, you're unlikely to be able to print one without a lot of trial & error, and looks like:

[image]

 From
https://console5.com/store/game-boy-advance-sp-hinge-replacement-case-hinge.html

However people have designed GBA cases - search your favourite STL websites for relevant links.  You may be able to find a case someone else has already designed and done debug.

Potentially useful tool https://3dmixers.com/m/275635-gba-sp-hinge-removal-tool-with-handle